# Rails joker has_one username, dancer has_one username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my rails app, I have a username model that is polymorphically attached to 2 models joker and dancer.

When creating a Joker, form sends a string that is the username for Joker. How should I go about setting this up so that rails does not throw an error when receiving a string instead of an AR object, for username?

Here is the code I have now.

```
class Joker < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :username

  has_one :username
end
```

and in create of Jokers_controller

```
@joker = Joker.new(params[:joker])
```

Rails throws this error:

```
Username(#19110) expected, got String(#9130)
```

So this is the form field

```
= form_for @joker do |f|
  - if @joker.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      h2 = "#{pluralize(@joker.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this joker from being saved:"
      ul
        - @joker.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          li = message


  = f.text_field :username
```

Comment: Please show us the form for this action. I suspect you're passing in the username as a string, rather than an association's id. Why is `Username` a model, anyway? Why must it be separate from the `jokers` table?

Comment: I made edit to show the form. I am not sure how to pass in the association id. The username needs to be a model because both Joker and Dancer need usernames and these usernames have to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you're passing `username` as a text field, when Rails is expecting it to be an instance of the `Username` class. What I would do is rather than having a `Username` model would be to have a validation on both the `Dancer` and `Joker` models that check the other for a conflicting username. This is simple:

```
 class Dancer < ActiveRecord::Base
   validate :unique_username

   # your model code goes here

   private

     def unique_username
       if Joker.find_by_username(username)
         errors.add(:username, "is already taken")
       end
     end
  end
```

So remove the `Username` model and related table and add just a `username` string field to both `dancers` and `jokers` and have this validation in the model.

Comment: but then how do i ensure that both have unique usernames? there is a possible race condition that can cause issues if both tables have their own unique index on usernames

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by switching the application to mongodb.